# ffmpeg does not recognize audio stream in video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flv

I have these flv files that exported from Adobe Connect and I want to extract their audio with ffmpeg. ffmpeg does not recognize the audio on some of them. This log is from one file that has issues:

```
>ffmpeg.exe -i r7anupl75gl_0_1965937.flv test1.mp3
ffmpeg version N-76123-g002b049 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg                                                                      
built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads                    
libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
libavcodec     57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
libavformat    57.  8.102 / 57.  8.102
libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[flv @ 0000000000522140] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1        

(Audio: none, 0 channels): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize'   
options
Input #0, flv, from 'r7anupl75gl_0_1965937.flv':
Metadata:
lasttimestamp   : 5026
lastkeyframetimestamp: 5022
audiodelay      : 0
canSeekToEnd    : false
creationdate    : unknown
metadatacreator : Manitu Group FLV MetaData Injector 2
videosize       : 251586025
audiosize       : 55776880
datasize        : 516
Duration: 01:23:47.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 489 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: vp6f, yuv420p, 1184x704, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: none, 0 channels
Output #0, mp3, to 'test1.mp3':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Note: audio codec is Nellymoser Asao and this command works successfully for some files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize'

The problem is in first 10-15 min the flv file doesn't actually have any audio. By increasing `probesize` and `analyzeduration` it looks further in the file to find audio and detect it.

In my scenario I have to set `analyzeduration` bigger than 5000000 (5 seconds).